# Canceling searches for an empty string in vim

Tags: search, vim

In my `vimrc` (I am using Nvim), I have mapped

```
noremap <C-f> <Esc>
noremap! <C-f> <Esc>

noremap / /\v
noremap ? ?\v
```

to automatically get [*very magic*](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic) regex search. However, I often press <kbd>/</kbd> by mistake (or change my mind about searching), and then press <kbd>C-f</kbd> (and sometimes <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to cancel it. However, this highlights the entire file (since everything matches `"\v"`). Sometimes I remember to delete twice before pressing <kbd>C-f</kbd>, but this jarringly moves me to the next instance of my previous search (an empty search `""`).

I could press <kbd>C-c</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel the search, but I am not used to it and I feel like I would have to move my fingers in uncomfortable ways to do so. Would it be possible make this simpler and more comfortable? Two solutions I can think of, but don't know how to implement, would be

1. Remap <kbd>C-f</kbd> to work as <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>C-c</kbd> while searching.

and

2. Make some sort of alias or change some setting, so that searching for `"\v"` (empty regex) or `""` (nothing) simply cancels the search.

Comment: I would advise to unlearn the habit to press Enter to *cancel* something.

Comment: And also to learn to avoid pressing / by mistake.

Comment: mkrieger1 Thanks, pressing Enter is a bad habit. I suppose that in my mind searching nothing equals not searching, which is where the habit comes from. It's not just pressing by mistake, sometimes I need to cancel a search and often I think I need to search for something but change my mind. I'll update the post to be a bit more clear.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but I have `map <Bslash> :nohls<CR>` in my vimrc so `\` will remove highlight from search. I also like it when I'm done with whatever I'm searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself! Apparently, changing

```
noremap <C-f> <Esc>
noremap! <C-f> <Esc>
```

to

```
noremap <C-f> <C-c>
noremap! <C-f> <C-c>
```

did the trick. I am not quite sure why that is, especially since pressing `Esc` seems to work equally well to `C-c`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple:

Change your habit of "press Enter to cancel" an operation. Also don't press `ctrl-f` for searching.

Why you have this strange habit?

- pressing `Enter` key after a command 90% will mean "Launch".
- in Vim, `ESC` would be much more often pressed than `Enter` also, general speaking, `Esc` key should be the one to "cancel" an opeartion
- what you meant "search nothing" in your comment, actually is not "search nothing", instead, it is "search anything"!
- Mapping `ctrl-f` in normal mode is a bad idea, it does "page down", and `ctrl-b` for "page up". They are pretty useful functions I think.
- Mapping `ctrl-f` in command/search mode is a bad idea too. `ctrl-f` brings you to the command window, there you can use full vim normal/insert commands to edit your commands. Very useful.

If you activated 'hlsearch', and want to remove the match highlighting, I  have this in vimrc, you can try it:

```
"clear hl search by pressing ,/
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>/  :noh<cr>
```

Comment: Kent. Thanks for your reply. I usually don't press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and have updated my question. It is because <kbd>Esc</kbd> is so widely used that I have mapped to a key combination (<kbd>C-f</kbd>) that only requires me to move one finger from <kbd>asdf</kbd>. I have separate bindings for page up/down.

Comment: I posted before finishing by mistake:

With "search nothing" I ment searching without "very magic". Searching "" (empty string) with `\v` matches everything, searching "" without `\v` matches my last search result.

Thanks for the suggestion. It's not quite what I'm looking for, but it functions as a workaround.